# XSLT New Line in CSV but not in the CSV

Tags: csv, xslt-1.0

I hope this doesn't confuse you.  I'm going to start from the perspective of an Excel file.  If I add the word "Cat" to a cell and then use the key combination Alt+Enter I get a new line within the cell so then I can enter the word "Dog".

The outcome of this is that I have two lines within the one cell with Cat and Dog on the lines.  I've written this in cell A2.

In A1 I wrote "Snake".
And in A3 I wrote "Hamster"

If I save this Excel file as CSV I get the following;

Snake
"CatDog"
Hamster

This is what I'm trying to achieve using XSLT.
But when I try this I do actually get a new line, like this;

Snake
"Cat
Dog"
Hamster

Which isn't what I'm after.
I'm receiving the data as a comma separated list from a different source (ie: not Excel).

Here is the XSLT code I'm trying to use at the moment;

```
<xsl:template name="parse-comma-separated">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
             <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))" />

            <xsl:call-template name="parse-comma-separated">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This appears to be putting a space between the Pets.
When I tried a straight up string-replace method (which works great if replacing commas with pipes) I actually get a new line which is kinda what I want but only in the cell, not a new line in the csv file.

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: I am afraid it *is* confusing. I suggest you post a small example of the XML input, and the *exact* output (as code) you expect to get as a result of transforming it. -- Note: if your output method is text, and you want newline characters to appear it, you must also consider the target platform - see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: When I save the Excel, that has the pets listed, as XML I can see this; Cat&#10;Dog ... which is what I thought I was doing with the above code.  When I finally get the csv file correct I'll be importing it into Excel.  I'm trying to change a comma separated list into a string that once imported into Excel will have the items displayed in a single cell but on a new line for each item (all within the same cell).